# Can I run my mobile app's back end on Uffizzi?

Tags: mobile, deployment, hosting, devops

So looking into Uffizzi, are there any restrictions as far as mobile goes? Specificially, it seems to deploy fine, but I wasn't sure if there are any more difficulties in connecting the back end for a mobile application than there are a Web app. I know permissions and those kinds of things are a bit different so wondered if Uffizzi handles this fine or is mainly for web apps?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to answer this is to cover what can run on uffizzi - which is just about anything.

You can deploy any application (front and/or backend) built with any language that runs on Linux, including Javascript, Python, C# (via .NET Core), PHP, Ruby, Go, Java, Scala, Clojure and more.

APIs, Web Apps, Mobile Back-ends are a few use cases of what you can run on uffizzi.

https://uffizzi.cloud/faq/